# A linear ODE from functional equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k\geq 0} a_k z^k
$$
be differentiable and suppose it satisfies

$$
((C-1)z^2+z)f(z)^2 - f(z) + 1 = 0.
$$
where $C$ is a constant.

Is there a way of finding a [linear ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) (if one exists) which $f(z)$ must satisfy?

EDIT:

If I instead start with the equation

$$
Czf(z)^2 - (1+(C-1)z)f(z) + 1 = 0,
$$

then I happen to know that

$$
(1−(C+1)z)f(z) = 1+(C−1)z+z(2(C+1)z-(C-1)^2z^2−1) f'(z)
$$

works (this is related to the Narayana polynomials).

I have no idea though how this ODE came about.
However if one solves for $f(z)$ in the functional equation above, then one gets

$$
f(z) = \frac{1-(C-1)z - \sqrt{1-2(C+1)z+(C-1)^2z^2}}{2z}
$$
which might give some hint.

Comment: You can just differentiate twice your given functional equation. At first it will be something of the form $a\cdot f^2(z)+b\cdot f(z)+c\cdot f'(z)=0$ and second step will give you desired linear ODE.

Comment: If I differentiate once I get something of the form $(2(C-1)z+1)f(z)^2 + ((C-1)z^2+z)f(z)f'(z) - f'(z)$ which is not linear (nor will be if i differentiate twice).

Comment: Why it won't be linear when you differentiate twice? What is $\frac{d}{dz}f^2(z)$?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dz}(f(z)^2) = 2f(z)f'(z)$